Запуск Яндекс карт по URL от текущего местоположения
Есть сайт на React JS, в нем используются яндекс карты.
На карте располагаются точки магазинов, которые имеют свои координаты, в балуне по точкам открывается информация по магазину и кнопка "проложить маршрут" по клику на эту кнопку нужно открыть яндекс карты с проложенным маршрутом от текущего местоположения пользователя до координат магазина.
Раньше это было реализовано так:
<a href={`https://yandex.ru/maps/?rtext=Current+Location~${shop.lat}%2C${shop.lon}`}
   rel='nofollow'
   target='blank'
   className={styles.route}
 >
   Построить маршрут
</a>

Но теперь Current+Location указывает на Остров Каррент, а не на текущее местоположение. Как это исправить? Есть ли какой-нибудь текстовый указатель на текущее местоположение?

Пожалуйста, отправьте пример, который вы составили в jsbin.com или codepen.io, или ссылку на страницу, где мы можем воспроизвести эту ситуацию.

А просто координаты без широты и долготы указать нельзя?
https://yandex.ru/maps/?rtext=60.026697,30.010813

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

данные динамически с бэка приходят, хардкодить смысла нет. Да и тут вопрос больше про определение этих самых координат по текущему местоположению

Схема построения маршрута по ссылке требует наличия исходных координат или названия объекта.
Если карта Яндекс создана на базе JS API 2.1, получать текущее местоположение можно через ymaps.geolocation.get(), подставляя полученные координаты в генерируемую ссылку.
